# SharePoint 2016 - Error when inserting a BDC webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, bdc

We are running SharePoint 2016, and up until now have had no problems with Business Data Catalogs.  Now when I try to access a page that has a DBC webpart on it I get this error and the page won't load at all:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
> resource required to service this request. Please review the following
> specific parse error details and modify your source file
> appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1"
> Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
> Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %><cc1:BdcDataSource runat="server"
> LobSystemInstanceName="ace_reporting" EntityNamespace="http://xxx/xxx"
> EntityName="BOR_WP1" EntityId="0" Enabled="True"
> ShowSampleData="False" SelectCommand="" InsertCommand=""
> UpdateCommand="" DeleteCommand=""></cc1:BdcDataSource>
>
> Source File: /SitePages/Dashboards.aspx    Line: 1
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET Version:4.8.4261.0

I even tried to add a brand new BDC webpart to an existing page that has nothing on it, and when I click to insert the webpart I get this error:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

I reset the BDC service from Central Admin and no change.  Like I said everything was working fine yesterday, any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new [external CT](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/create-external-content-type-sharepoint/)

Comment: No, but I did reboot the servers in the farm and things Started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted all the servers in the server farm and things started working after that

Comment: Rebooting is not considered a solution especially in a production environment, you should merge logs from the SP servers then trace the log to can identify the root cause of the issue  check also **[How to merge logs and use ULS viewer](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/uls-viewer-tool/)**

Comment: Well with the production site down I didn't have too many options, so I had to try what I could.  There was very little help in the log files.